# OSX equivalent of IsWindowVisible()?

Tags: macos

Given a process PID, is there a system call that would return whether or not the process is "visible" to the user?

Comment: Be more specific:  Do you want to know whether the process has an icon visible in the Dock, or whether it owns a window that is visible and not obscured by any other window, or whether it owns a window that would be visible if there weren't other windows in the way, or what?

Comment: Fair point.  The goal is to detect processes that are running which have a window that *could* be visible to the user (daemon processes wouldn't have one, normally) - the goal is to tell the user that, for instance, "Process X is running, please close it down in order to continue" (this is for an exam environment)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` to get an `NSArray` of `NSRunningApplication`s describing the running applications including your own.  The `activationPolicy` property can be used to identify background-only applications so you can ignore them.

For an exam environment, you might alternatively consider the [kiosk mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) options.